# Chrome vs Firefox Javascript behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, alert

Here's the "data:" URI, load this in browser.

```
data:text/html,<script>alert("#")</script>
```

I get alert() executed in Chrome, but not in Firefox.
Firefox removes "#" character and all the following characters.
How can I make FF to alert("#")?

Update: I understand the "#" fragment part, but the question is more like "Why did Chrome ignore the "fragment" case and consider it as a normal character, when FF didn't?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data portion of a data URI must be encoded, `#` as a literal character is not allowed. From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

> The data, separated from the preceding part by a comma (`,`). The data is a sequence of octets represented as characters. Permitted characters within a data URI are the ASCII characters for the lowercase and uppercase letters of the modern English alphabet, and the Arabic numerals. Octets represented by any other character must be percent-encoded, as in `%26` for an ampersand (`&`).

...which cites [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

So your data URI should be:

```
data:text/html,%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22%23%22)%3C%2Fscript%3E
```

...which works in both Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<a href="data:text/html,%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22%23%22)%3C%2Fscript%3E">Click here</a>
```

You can get the URI data using JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent`, e.g.:

```
var dataUri = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent('<script>alert("#")</script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

A `#` has special meaning in a URL (it indicates the start of the fragment part). You have to encode it as `%23` to include it as data.